# NullPointerException VideoView and MediaController on Fragment in android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, show, fragment, mediacontroller

I am developing Galaxy Tab 10.1 app by using honeycomb 3.1 and i have a videoview and mediacontroller in fragment on the right side. I defined VideoView and MediaController in Layout xml file and instantiate and manipulate them in the related java file.

As you guys konw, in the java file, i set VideoView's controller to MediaController and set MediaController's media player to VideoView, i defined.

Below is fragment layout xml file

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <MediaController
        android:id="@+id/controller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and java code file is below

```
public class ContentFragment extends Fragment {
    private VideoView mVideo;
    private MediaController mController;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content, null);
        mVideo = (VideoView)view.findViewById(R.id.video);
        mController = (MediaController)view.findViewById(R.id.controller);
        mVideo.setMediaController(mController);
        mController.setMediaPlayer(mVideo);

        return view;
    }

    public void playVideo(String path) {
        mVideo.setVideoPath(path);
        mVideo.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

But while running this app, there occurs

> NullPointerException with
>   android.widget.MediaController.show(MediaController.java:305)

I tried to solve this error a whole day but i can't get the reason why. actullay there isn't enought information for this.
Dose any body know what i did wrong? or have solutions?
Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but instead of defining the MediaController in XML, you should instantiate it programatically (see [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html)):

```
mController = new MediaController(getActivity());
```

And then attach it to the VideoView:

```
mVideo.setMediaController(mController);
```

Also, as far as I can tell, adding `mController.setMediaPlayer(mVideo);` is pointless since the call to setMediaController seems to take care of that as well.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i had tried your code. what i want is MideaController is displayed on the same fragment. your code, honeycomb displays MediaController on the bottom and center-horizontal of main display.

Comment: @diveto Then try calling setAnchorView(View view) on the mController.

Comment: actually, i implemented a mediacontroller like controller based on mediacontroller class and placed it in a fragment. so, i solved it. anyway thanks for your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the ContentFragment class to static class:

```
public static class ContentFragment extends Fragment { 
    [...]
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's even possible if he's not declared `ContentFragment` as an inner class.